# cannot remove youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I was trying to uninstall youtube-dl, but I got stuck. I'm using `sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl` but it still present in my distro and can run. This I get from terminal `youtube-dl/hirsute,hirsute 2021.04.07-0ubuntu1 all`

Comment: A few questions: (1) how did you install it? [apt / snap / pip / other] (2) which version of Ubuntu are you running? This will make it easier for someone to offer a specific solution, as there are many ways to install that particular tool.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **output** of the command(s) you are attempting to use to remove the software alongside the command used

Comment: What are the outputs of `which youtube-dl` and `pip3 list`? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1360304/edit) to add the outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you installed with `pip` (as you mentioned in the comment above), you also need to uninstall with `pip`. `apt` does not know about it.

```
pip3 uninstall youtube-dl
```

In case you used sudo during installation, you also need to add sudo during removal.

Comment: discover that by installing flatpak help to remove this youtube-dl